# How do you evaluate a html checkbox using C#?

Tags: c#, html, mysql, razor

I'm trying to send one of two different pieces of data to a database, depending on whether the user has checked an html checkbox. I can't figure out how to evaluate the checkbox using C#, **without** MVC. Here's what I've been trying in a simplified form:

```
@{
    var Category = "";
    var AltCategory = "";

    var db = Database.Open("Inventory");

    var Checkbox_value =(Request["altCategory_checkbox"]=="on") ? true : false;

    if(IsPost && Validation.IsValid()){
        Category = Request.Form["ListCategory"];
        AltCategory = Request.Form["AltCategory"];

        if(Checkbox_value = true){
            Funcs.AddNewProduct(Category);
        }
        else{
            Funcs.AddNewProduct(AltCategory);
        }
        Response.Redirect("~/Members/Products");}
}
```

And the html:

```
  <form method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <p><label for="Category">Category:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Category" value="@Request.Form["Category"]" />
      </p>

    <input type="checkbox" name="altCategory_checkbox" id="altCategory_checkbox">
    <label for="altCategory_checkbox">Add new category?</label> 

      <p><label for="AltCategory">New category:</label>
         <input type="text" name="New category" value="@Request.Form["AltCategory"]" />
      </p>

         <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Add product" /></p> 

    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I apologize if this is a trivial question.

Comment: Are you dealing with request and db in Razor page? That's really bad idea. Don't you want to place code in controller?

Comment: But if it's working shouldn't it be `Request["altCategory_checkbox"]=="true"`?

Comment: @teovankot I'm a bit of a novice in web development, but as I understand it, controllers are a part of MVC? I'm not using MVC. Please let me know if that's not the case. I've tried your suggestion regarding `Request["altCategory_checkbox"]=="true"`, and it seemingly always evaluates to `false`. It's an improvement on the previous code though, since it didn't evaluate to anything before.

Comment: I just can't understand what are you trying to do. In your form i can't see checkbox

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to include the the checkbox in my question: 
        `<input type="checkbox" name="altCategory_checkbox" id="altCategory_checkbox">`
`<label for="altCategory_checkbox">Add new category?</label>`
Edit: I'm sorry this looks horrible, but I hope you can read it.

Comment: So please add it to your question. You can edit it easily

Comment: I was under the impression that it was frowned upon to edit the original question, but I've done so now. Thank you for your time so far.

Comment: Have you checked in degugger what's comes to you? I just don't see full picture what's happened after form post. I even don't see submit button

Comment: I've included the Submit button as well now. In case it wasn't clear, depending on the checkbox, I want to call the function `AddNewProduct` with input from either the `Category` or the `AltCategory` input boxes. The code doesn't fail, but it always adds the product using `Category`, regardless of checking the checkbox or not. This would seem to suggest, that the `var Checkbox_value =(Request["altCategory_checkbox"]=="true") ? true : false;` always evaluates to false, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following ended up being a solution:

```
 @{
    var Category = "";
    var AltCategory = ""; 

    var db = Database.Open("Inventory");

    if(IsPost){
        Category = Request.Form["ListCategory"];
        AltCategory = Request.Form["AltCategory"];
        bool CategoryCheckbox = Request["CategoryCheckbox"].AsBool(); 

        if(CategoryCheckbox){
            Funcs.AddNewProduct(Category);
        }
        else{
            Funcs.AddNewProduct(AltCategory);
        }
        Response.Redirect("~/Members/Products");}
}
```

With html:

```
  <form method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <p><label for="Category">Category:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Category" value="@Request.Form["Category"]" />
      </p>

    @Html.CheckBox("CategoryCheckbox", new { value = "true" })
    <label for="CategoryCheckbox">Add new category?</label>

      <p><label for="AltCategory">New category:</label>
         <input type="text" name="New category" value="@Request.Form["AltCategory"]" />
      </p>

         <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Add product" /></p> 

    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

The trick is to read the checkbox as a `bool` using `bool CategoryCheckbox = Request["CategoryCheckbox"].AsBool();`